# How can I attach a react-tiny-popover Popover to an arbitraty element, instead of the child?

Tags: reactjs

I have a complex grid in a React app, and I want to show details relating to a cell in a popover. I am using `react-tiny-popover` but my grid has many cells and a complex implementation, so the standard way of marking up the `Popover` is not feasible:

```
const DetailedCell = ({ details }) => <Popover content={details}> <Cell ... /> </Popover>; // Not feasible
```

Instead, I will keep track of the "target" cell that should currently have details displayed. How can I render a single `Popover` that is attached to the target cell and follows it around?

```
const DetailsPopover = () => undefined; // TODO how can this be implemented?

const MyPage = () => {
  // ...

  const [target, setTarget] = useState(null);
  return <>
    <ComplexGrid onSelectCell={setTarget} ... />
    {target && <DetailsPopover target={target.domElement}>
      Details of {getCellTitle(target)}: ...
    </DetailsPopover>}
  </>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `React.forwardRef` to implement `DetailsPopover` using the `react-tiny-popover` v7 API, by passing an empty component to `Popover` that 'forwards' its ref to whichever element you want:

```
const RefTarget = React.forwardRef(({ target }, ref) => {
  if (typeof ref === 'function') ref(target); // Forward target to callback refs.
  else ref.current = target; // Forward target to object refs.

  return null; // Don't render anything.
});

const TargetedPopover = ({ targetElement, children, ...props }) =>
  <Popover isOpen={true} content={children} {...props}>
    <RefTarget target={targetElement} />
  </Popover>
```